# Does a random seed set via numpy.random.seed maintain across submodules?

Tags: python, numpy, random

If I set a seed for my RNG e.g. `numpy.random.seed(0)` and I call a submodule, will the RNG's state be maintained?

e.g.

```
# some_lib.py
def do_thing():
  return numpy.random.rand()
```

```
# parent module
import some_lib
numpy.seed(0)
...
some_lib.do_thing()
```

Will the numpy state set by the parent be used by the child?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The seed is a global value for all uses of `numpy`. So as long as the child module doesn't reseed it, or pull values from it non-deterministically (effectively adjusting it to a new seed based on advancing the old), then the seed will be preserved.

Most PRNG libraries behave this way, because the alternative is pretty useless; for reproducible tests, you *want* to be able to set the seed once, and have everything rely on that stable seed. If there was a per-module seed, the testing module couldn't seed the PRNG used by the module being tested.

Comment: The design of Python helps. Imported modules are singletons, re-importing in a different place returns a reference to the same module.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yup. The `reload` function can mess with this a bit, as can manually mucking with `sys.modules`, but that sort of nonsense should only occur in interactive sessions, not in "real" code.

Answer (score 2):

In testing, it appears that numpy's RNG state is maintained by the child process.